# Reading a text file then performing a character count and printing the relative frequency of each one

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, printf, bufferedreader

I'm looking to perform a character count on a text file and then display each one with it's relative frequency to the rest of the characters, but I'm presently getting just blank console back. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;


public class RelativeFrequency {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       File file1 = new File("Rf.txt");
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file1));
           System.out.println("Letter Frequency");

        int nextChar;
        char ch;

        int[] count = new int[26];

        while ((nextChar = in.read()) != -1) {
          ch = ((char) nextChar);
          if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
          count[ch - 'a']++;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
          System.out.printf("", i + 'A', count[i]);

        }



in.close();

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your printf statement isn't formatted correctly

```
System.out.printf("%c %d", i + 'A', count[i]);
```

Comment: `%i` isn't valid in java.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `printf` is wrong

```
// Assuming you want each letter count on one line
System.out.printf("%c = %d\n", i + 'A', count[i]);
```

Also you should call `tolower` on ch before comparing with `if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')`

```
ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
```

Comment: Cheers, but it's all lower case in the text file.