# counting numbers in a text file

Tags: java, numbers, counter, frequency

I happened to modify the source code as seen in the topic,"**[Reading a text file then performing a character count and printing the relative frequency of each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080766/reading-a-text-file-then-performing-a-character-count-and-printing-the-relative)**". 
   I changed it in such a way that the non-alphabetic characters would also be counted (see the source code below)...

```
import java.io.*;

public class letterfrequency {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File ("letternumberfrequency.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file1));

        int nextChar;
        int other = 0;
        char ch;

        int [] count = new int [26];

        while ((nextChar = in.read())!= -1) {
            ch = ((char)nextChar);
            ch = Character.toLowerCase (ch);
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
              count [ch- 'a']++;
            else
              other ++;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
            System.out.printf ("%c = %d \n", i+ 'A', count [i]);
        }

        System.out.println ("Non-alphabetic characters: " + other);
        in.close ();
    }
}
```

But, let's just say that now I have the following characters in the text file, "letternumberfrequency.txt":
**71 geese - 83 cars - 58 cows- 64 mooses- 100 ants- 69 bangles- 90 molehills - 87 noses**

The numbers inside that text file would be considered as strings, am I right?
But I want to extract the numbers so that I can also be able to count their frequency - not as individual digits but as whole numbers (that is how many "71", "83", "58", "64", etc. are there...).
Would using "Double.parseDouble ()" help?

Answer (score 0):

> Would using "Double.parseDouble ()" help?

No, it would not.

You would first split the file on the `"-"` String, then split the found tokens again on the `" "` String, trim the result and use `Integer.parseInt(...)` because the number Strings surely represent ints, not doubles.